# Is Sydler's theorem concerning Dehn invariants constructive?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra, scissors-congruence

Sydler proved something of a converse to Dehn's negative resolution
of Hilbert's 3rd problem. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Dehn_invariant), Sydler showed that
"every two Euclidean polyhedra with the same volumes and Dehn invariants can be cut up and reassembled into each other."

My question is: Is Sylder's proof constructive in the sense that
it implies an algorithm?

> Sydler, J.-P., "Conditions nécessaires et suffisantes pour l'équivalence des polyèdres de l'espace euclidien à trois dimensions." *Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici* **40**, pp 43–80, 1965,
> doi:[10.1007/BF02564364](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02564364), [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/139296).

A secondary question: Does anyone know if an English
translation of his paper is available?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I went through the proof awhile ago thinking I should write it up in my book.  I ended up including only some of the lemmas I found especially elegant (see section 16).  The proof is fundamentally algebraic, but every step can in principle be replaced by a constructive argument.  It's just not particularly "effective", but neither is Bolyai–Gerwien theorem I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I thank John McCleary for pointing me to Jessen's work, and from there
I found the useful thesis of Schröder.
I have not yet assessed these papers.

> Jessen, Børge. "The algebra of polyhedra and the Dehn-Sydler theorem." *Mathematica Scandinavica* 22, no. 2 (1969): 241-256.
> [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24489773).

> Jessen, Børge, Jørgen Karpf, and Anders Thorup. "Some functional equations in groups and rings." *Mathematica Scandinavica* 22, no. 2 (1969): 257-265.
> [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24489773).

> Felix Schröder.
> "Decomposability and the Dehn Invariant."
> Thesis, TU Berlin. 2015.
> [PDF download](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efschroed/BAFelixSchroeder.pdf).